# s3 getObject breaks when file size over 100mb

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-s3

I'm working on a file upload and download service with React and Node. I'm hosting files on Digital Ocean which uses AWS S3. The following code works like a champ (straight from their documentation).

`   // OG code
app.get("/test-download/:id", (req, res) => {
var params = {
Bucket: secretBucketName,
Key: secretKeyStuff
};

```
s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
  //
  console.log(data);
  //
  if (!err) {
    res.send({ data, key: params.Key });
  } else {
  //An error occurred
    console.log({ err });
  }
 });
});`
```

However, anytime I attempt to download a file that's been uploaded previously that's over 100 MB either the server crashes, I get a JavaScript heap out of memory, or some other error.

So, I've attempted to stream the getObject request and can run that successfully. However, I get a strange-looking response on the front end and I'm not sure whether I need to convert the data before streaming or convert it afterward...

```
app.get("/test-download/:id", (req, res) => {
var params = {
  Bucket: secretBucketName,
  Key: secretKeyStuff
};

// This Stream
s3.getObject(params)
  .createReadStream()
  .pipe(res)
  .on("finish", () => {
    console.log("** done");
  });
 });
```

Front-end code.

```
downloadFile = (id, name, type) => {
axios
  .get(
    `/test-download/${id}`,
    this.props.handleSnackBar("Your download has been started.")
  )
  .then(res => {
    download(
      // Stream doesn't recognize res.data.data.Body.data
     // I'm assuming b/c of the data format in which is being returned
      new Blob([new Uint8Array(res.data.data)], { type: "octet/stream" }),
      `${name}.${type}`
    );
    console.log(res.data);
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

};

Front-end response with node stream.

[Front end response with node stream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvsYg.png)

Any ideas on what this image is conveying? And if you could point me in the right direction you would be the greatest.` enter code here

Comment: Basically running this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html#createReadStream-property . I can log the raw HTTP body contents, but is there a method in which to convert/transform?

Comment: The question is better formatted and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55460503/javascript-heap-out-of-memory-s3-getobject-in-react-node-app

Answer (score 0):

IN short : 80 mb is the limit when you trying to use this nodejs method to read the file.