# JavaScript heap out of memory | s3.getObject in React/Node app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

We have a React/Node app hosted on Digital Ocean. We're also utilizing Digital Ocean spaces which is interoperable with AWS S3 for Object storage. Basically, the app is sort of an in-house dropbox. We have Admins who are able to create folders and upload content to these folders. We then have Clients who are able to login and download any files we allow them access to.

We're successfully able to upload all files to Digital Ocean Spaces. No matter how large/small they are.

The problem is when we try to download (as Admin or Client) any content that is over 100MB in size we experience a JavaScript Heap out of memory error. This error appears on the Backend of the system.

Some solutions we've attempted to administer are:

1. Provisioning the VM with more more ram
2. Increase the browser memory '--max-old-space-size'
3. Enabling the Digital Ocean CDN to stream content through edge servers
4. Manually streaming file data to our backend and then sending it to the frontend

Frontend code

```
downloadFile = (id, name, type) => {
axios
  .get(
    `/test-download/${id}`,
    this.props.handleSnackBar(
      "Your download has been started. Please wait."
    )
  )

  .then(res => {
    download(

      new Blob([new Uint8Array(res.data.data.Body.data)]),
      `${name}.${type}`
    );
    console.log(res);

    console.log(res.data.data.Body),
      this.props.handleSnackBar("Your download is now ready.");
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

Backend code

```
app.get("/test-download/:id", (req, res) => {
var params = {
  Bucket: bucketName,
  Key: req.params.id
};

s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
  //
  console.log(data);
  //
  if (!err) {

    res.send({ data, key: params.Key });
  } else {
    console.log({ err }); // an error occurred
  }
});
});
```

Backend code with stream

```
app.get("/test-download/:id", (req, res) => {
var params = {
  Bucket: bucketName,
  Key: req.params.id
};
// TRY

const fileRequest = s3.getObject(params);

let chunks = [];
fileRequest
  .createReadStream()

  .on("data", function(data) {
    console.log(`Received ${data.length} bytes of data`);
    chunks.push(data);
  })
  .on("end", function() {
    console.log("no more data");
    bufferData = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    console.log(bufferData);
    res.send({ bufferData, key: params.Key });
  });

});
```

So, basically I'm sort of stuck. Any assistance that can be offered is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Marcos, I revisited the piping code we had attempted. But now fully understanding the raw data response I was receiving from the `createReadStream().pipe()` I was able to convert the data.

Frontend code

```
app.get("/test-download/:id", (req, res) => {
var params = {
  Bucket: bucketName,
  Key: req.params.id
};

s3.getObject(params)
  .createReadStream()
  .pipe(res)
  .on("finish", () => {
    console.log("** done");
  });
});
```

Backend code

```
downloadFile = (id, name, type) => {
axios
  .get(
    `/test-download/${id}`,
    { responseType: "arraybuffer" },
    this.props.handleSnackBar(
      "Your download has been started. Please wait."
    )
  )
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    download(res.data, `${name}.${type}`);
    this.props.handleSnackBar("Your download is now ready.");
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

Comment: What is called the "Frontend code" actually looks like the "Backend code" and vice versa

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that while you're using `streams` on the last snippet, you buffer all the chunks defeating the purpose of using streams.

What you should do instead is `.pipe` directly to the response, this way the memory used will be quite low.

```
app.get("/test-download/:id", (req, res) => {
    const params = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: req.params.id
    };

    s3.getObject(params)
        .createReadStream()
        .pipe(res);

});
```

Have in mind that now you're not responding a `JSON` object, so the client should be changed.

Comment: That would explain the interesting response data :) So now the client side code would need to convert that to json?

Comment: Why do you need to convert it to JSON? You're using `new Uint8Array(res.data.data.Body.data)` in the front end. just use `new Uint8Array(res.data)` or `new Uint8Array(res.data.data)` (I'm not familiar with how to access the response in that library)

Comment: The data I'm seeing is, "�0�wO��]j��hW��A�Ap���:��<B^�tS�t+��"���/�n��3Qҕ�$�=?�q*�m&;:���h�ZȆY��K3Ʃ�2 뗷�K�(5" `Uint8Array(res.data)` just returns an empty array. Likewise, `new Blob([new Uint8Array(res.data)])` returns an empty object.

Comment: That's the raw file you're downloading. Hit the URL without axios, directly on the browser, you will get the downloaded file. You can set the appropiate headers to to download, `content-disposition` and so on.

Comment: Point you somewhere for what exactly? What happens if you just access :`/test-download/54` in the browser?

Comment: The url itself won’t work because it’s a private file. That’s why we’re using s3 with the bucket parameters.

Comment: I don't say the s3 URL, I mean your route URL... the one from the script I wrote.